# Bokeh streaming issue: shifting line

Tags: bokeh

I have the following code:

```
import random
import datetime as dt

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure


source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x = [], y = []
))

p = figure(plot_height=250, plot_width=400, tools="save",
           x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_location="right")
p.x_range.follow = "end"
p.x_range.follow_interval = 5000  # ms
p.line(x='x', y='y', color='red', source=source)

cur_time = dt.datetime.now()
step = dt.timedelta(seconds=1)

def update():
    global cur_time, step
    new_data = dict(x=[], y=[])
    new_data['x'].append(cur_time)
    new_data['y'].append(random.randint(1, 100))
    cur_time += step
    source.stream(new_data, 60)  # how many data are saved

curdoc().add_root(p)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 500)
```

I wanted to cut data, so I added rollover parameter to [stream method](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource.stream). At first it's OK:

[image]

But after a while the line begins to shift:

[image]

Why does it work like that? And how to fix this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import datetime as dt

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure


source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x = [], y = []
))

p = figure(plot_height=250, plot_width=400, tools="save",
           x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_location="right")
# p.x_range.follow = "end" #***** THIS IS YOUR ISSUE *****
p.x_range.follow_interval = 500  # ms
p.line(x='x', y='y', color='red', source=source)

cur_time = dt.datetime.now()
step = dt.timedelta(seconds=1)

def update():
    global cur_time, step
    new_data = dict(x=[], y=[])
    new_data['x'].append(cur_time)
    new_data['y'].append(random.randint(1, 100))
    cur_time += step
    source.stream(new_data, 60)  # how many data are saved

curdoc().add_root(p)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 50)
```

See my edits. The x_range.follow is not needed, see

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/reference/models/ranges.html